# Closing Popover Window from a different class (Ionic, Typescript)

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, popover

My problem is that a function, which i import from another class, will not get called and neither gets recognised by the parser. The Popover cant be closed. I tried several similar solutions but none of them worked for me. I am not that much into typescript so i hope i do nothing wrong

```
export function dismissWindow() {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.page.scss'],
})

export class UserPage implements OnInit {
  public  popover;

 //Pop up Informationen rechts oben
  async notifications(ev: any) {  
    this.popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({  
      component: NotificationsComponent,  
      event: ev,  
      animated: true,  
      showBackdrop: true  
    }); 

    return await this.popover.present();  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public dismissWindow(){
    console.log("Dismiss got called");
    this.popover.dismiss();
  }
}
```

```
import { UserPage } from './../user/user.page';
import { dismissWindow} from './../user/user.page';

LogOut() {
  console.log("in logout method")
  dismissWindow();
  console.log("Call From Logout");
  this.router.navigate(['login'])
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call the `this.popover.dismiss()` from the logout page? Just load the popovercontroller back in the page and you will get the same functionality.

Comment: I tried this but if you navigate back to the previous page then multiple popups still exist on present. It feels like the popups are not destroyed if you dismiss from inside the component using the PopoverController. Perhaps it dismiss must be called on the popover instance itself outside the component?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `popoverCtrl` is a service instance, if yes then in the second file inject the service and create another service to keep track of opened popovers or use existing service.

Basically keeping track of the opened popover at a central place such as a singleton service which can be injected in any component and accessed.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
class UtilService {
    private _popover;

    set openedPopover(popover) {
        this._popover = popover;
    }

    closePopover() {
        if(this._popover) {
            this._popover.dismiss();
            this._popover = null;
        }
    }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.page.scss'],
})

export class UserPage implements OnInit {
  public  popover;

  constructor(private utilService: UtilService) {}
 //Pop up Informationen rechts oben
  async notifications(ev: any) {  
    this.popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({  
      component: NotificationsComponent,  
      event: ev,  
      animated: true,  
      showBackdrop: true  
    }); 

    this.utilSerivce.openedPopover(this.popover);
    return await this.popover.present();  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public dismissWindow(){
    console.log("Dismiss got called");
    //this.popover.dismiss();
    this.utilService.closePopover(this.popover);
  }
}

class YourClass {
    constructor(private utilService: UtilService) {}

    LogOut() {
        this.utilService.closePopover(this.popover);
    }
}
```